# Error to reach in "openById"

Tags: google-apps-script

It's my first time, I'm sorry for my English, I'm not really good with this language.

I use Google SpreadSheet and Google App Script to automate.
All functions work on my computer but when I try on another computer, there is an error message:

> "Impossible to access in OpenByID"

All my sheets are shared. The code works on my computer.

My code:

```
var DSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("148g16PDJ8GLVg9Q6_ntQYEs4iKL36Oo_rLlZn1xQyvU");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(DSheet);
var rawSheet = DSheet.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");

var DMEP = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bB77ZGQORV_X7MB2v1qYdOssK0Gsj0QAiynbvy8jeMA");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(DMEP);
var EnrMep = DMEP.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");

var DStat = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1mm90NtmCFLNO7dzx2Sdefel9xInObNzRmHusK6hbHKY");
var EnrStat = DStat.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");

var DRot = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dOAPJsr8cLYOQMmaCq6WlPy9ruZXGOg2S3Dbgor4bE8");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(DRot);
var EnrRot = DRot.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");

var DProt = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rq8bpHoY5pnbEAhC8KzVz2a_yhu2yJBGfmc4vGJFucQ");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(DProt);
var EnrProt = DProt.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");

var Dass = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1c1nbJhxoOHSnM1P46SLumW3g9mkEXW9JMGkIviH-Vps");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(Dass);
var EnrAss = Dass.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you log-in the same email in the other computer?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are sharing your sheet with other person check the share settings.

In case that doesn't work follow these steps:

- Try to access it on a incognito window
- Clear cache and data
- Logout from any google account and login again.

Hope it helps!